# How to use python to print strings as processing like this

Tags: python, string, printing

I want to write a function to print out string like this:

```
Found xxxx...
```

for x is result calculating by another function. It only print one line, sequential, but not one time. Example: I want to print my_name but it'll be m.... and my.... and my_...., at only line.
Can i do this with python?
Sorry I can't explain clearly by english.

### UPDATE

Example code;

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com/?get='
list = ['black', 'white', 'pink']

def get_num(id):
    num = requests.get(url+id).text
    return num
def print_out():
    for i in list:
        num = get_num(i)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Now at main I want to print out 2...  (for example, first get_num value is 2) and after calculating 2nd loop print_out, such as 5, it will update 25...
    #But not like this:
    #2...
    #25...
    #25x...
    #I want to it update on one line :)
```

Comment: Try with ``sys.stdout.write`` instead of ``print``

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Updated my example code!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what it is you are trying to do. Can you show an exact sample output of what you are looking for?

Comment: @idjaw Hmmm, it will print out look like you type the values

Comment: So you are looking for this: `2 25 25x`?

Comment: https://youtu.be/uVsG7vUTOmA?t=5m26s output like sqlmap bro

Comment: So on each new line you are looking for something like this: On line 1 `Stuff XYZ` and then on line 2 `Things ABC` and line 3 `Bolts 123`. So those will each be on their own line. You want the key value pair on each line. Is that it?

Comment: No no, watch video please :( imagine my values to printing out is 'infomation_schema' and I want to it look like the video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91294/discussion-between-idjaw-and-user3600331).

Comment: please go to the chat link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to print your output all in the same line, and you are using Python 2.7, you can do a couple of things.

**First Method Py2.7**
Simply doing this:

```
# Note the comma at the end
print('stuff'),
```

Will keep the print on the same line but there will be a space in between

**Second Method Py2.7**

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("stuff")
```

This will print everything on the same line without a space. Be careful, however, as it only takes type `str`. If you pass an `int` you will get an exception.

So, in a code example, to illustrate the usage of both you can do something like this:

```
import sys
def foo():
    data = ["stuff"]
    print("Found: "),
    for i in data:
        sys.stdout.write(i)
    #if you want a new line...just print
    print("")

foo()
```

Output:
`Found: stuff`

**Python 3 Info**

Just to add extra info about using this in Python 3, you can simply do this instead:

`print("stuff", end="")`

Output example taken from docs [here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_print.php)

```
>>> for i in range(4):
...     print(i, end=" ")
... 
0 1 2 3 >>> 
>>> for i in range(4):
...     print(i, end=" :-) ")
... 
0 :-) 1 :-) 2 :-) 3 :-) >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "my_name"
for letter in range(len(s)):
    print("Found",s[0:letter+1])
```

Instead of 's' you can just call function with your desired return value.